# Calculation based on the reference to another key in a dictionary,

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

If two dictionaries are given :

```
valuedict = {1: 10.0, 2: 20.0, 3:30.0}
Vardict1    = {'Var1' : "1 + 2 + 3", 'Var2' : "2" , 'Var3':  "1 + 2", 'Var4' : "3 - 2"}
```

How to create a new dictionary with the Calculation of values based upon the expression.

```
Output :- {'Var1' : 60.0, 'Var2': 20.0, 'Var3': 30.0, 'Var4': 10.0}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Yes Sir understood! Wouldn't have asked if I was capable of doing it by myself. Unfortunately, I can't become a pro like you but still it is worth a try. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses regex to parse the expression and then builds the result from left to right:

```py
import re

def eval_exp(exp):
    parts = re.findall(r'\d+|[+-]', exp)
    result = valuedict[int(parts[0])]
    for i in range(1, len(parts), 2):
        op = parts[i]
        value = valuedict[int(parts[i+1])]
        result += value if op == '+' else -value
    return result

{ k : eval_exp(v) for k, v in Vardict1.items() }
```

Output:

```
{'Var1': 60.0, 'Var2': 20.0, 'Var3': 30.0, 'Var4': 10.0}
```

Note this assumes the only operators are `+` and `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using a regex and a dictionary comprehension (works only with +/- operators):

```
import re
out = {k: sum(valuedict.get(int(b), 0)*(-1 if a=='-' else 1)
              for a,b in re.findall('(?:(-)\s)?(\d+)', v))
       for k,v in Vardict1.items()}
```

output:

```
{'Var1': 60.0, 'Var2': 20.0, 'Var3': 30.0, 'Var4': 10.0}
```

intermediates steps:

```
# finding the numbers and minus sign
[re.findall('(?:(-)\s)?(\d+)', v) for v in Vardict1.values()]

[[('', '1'), ('', '2'), ('', '3')],
 [('', '2')],
 [('', '1'), ('', '2')],
 [('', '3'), ('-', '2')]]

# getting the dictionary values modified if a minus sign is present

[[valuedict.get(int(b), 0)*(-1 if a=='-' else 1)
  for a,b in re.findall('(?:(-)\s)?(\d+)', v)]
 for v in Vardict1.values()]

[[10.0, 20.0, 30.0], [20.0], [10.0, 20.0], [30.0, -20.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

valuedict = {1: 10.0, 2: 20.0, 3:30.0}
Vardict1    = {'Var1' : "1 + 2 + 3", 'Var2' : "2" , 'Var3':  "1 + 2", 'Var4' : "3 - 2"}
for i in Vardict1:
    if i=='Var1':
       Vardict1[i]= valuedict[1]+valuedict[2]+valuedict[3]
        
    elif i=='Var2':
       Vardict1[i] =valuedict[2]
        
    else:
        
        Vardict1[i]=valuedict[3] -valuedict[2]
        
print(Vardict1)
```